# Why do we have the fact that $\|A-B\|_2\le d\epsilon_n \, ? $

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, statistics

For two symmetric and semi-positive covariance matrices $A$ and $B$ of size $d\times d$, let
$\epsilon_n=\max_{j,k}|A_{jk}-B_{jk}|.
$
Why do we have the fact that
$$
\|A-B\|_2\le d\epsilon_n \, ?
$$

This means
$$
\|A-B\|_2\le d\max_{j,k}|A_{jk}-B_{jk}|
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $M = A - B$. Let $\|\cdot\|_F$ denote the Frobenius norm. Note that
$$
\|M\|_2^2 \leq \|M\|_F^2 = \sum_{i,j} |M_{jk}|^2 \leq d^2 \max_{j,k} |M_{j,k}|^2 = d^2 \epsilon_n^2.
$$

Comment: Is $\|\cdot\|_2$ the same as the Frobenius norm?

Comment: @quas Depends on the context. In the context that I am most familiar with, $\|\cdot\|_2$ refers to the spectral norm, i.e. the maximal singular value, so this is what I assumed.